# How to make a library that has been generated with nx, buildable?

Tags: build, monorepo, nomachine-nx

I generated a library with nx but i forgot to make it buildable.

I have no clue what to di to fix this

Answer (score 0):

For making an existing library publishable, you will have to do the following steps:

1. Add package.json to your lib root folder
2. Install npm i ng-packagr@latest
3. Add ng-package.json file to your lib root folder
4. Modify the project.json file of your lib to include the build task along with the ts config

`"targets": { "build": { "executor": "@nrwl/angular:package", "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/dist/{projectRoot}"], "options": { "project": "libs/shared-lib/ng-package.json" }, "configurations": { "production": { "tsConfig": "libs/shared-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json" }, "development": { "tsConfig": "libs/shared-lib/tsconfig.lib.json" } }, "defaultConfiguration": "production" }`

After this you should be able to build your library using the nx build task

npx nx run your-lib:build